# Block alt + tab in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, blocking

I'm developing one kiosk software, to run over Windows 7.

I need to block key sequences like alt + tab, alt + F4 etc. How can I block it?

Comment: Remove the keys from the keyboard :)

Comment: OK! Nice try! Remove the keys... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Autohotkey](http://autohotkey.com) can do this in a single line:

```
!tab::return
```

It's useful for blocking all of the common nasty key combinations you wouldn't want used on a kiosk, such as Alt+F4, Ctrl-W (depending on browser used), F11, and so on.

Comment: How to use this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reviewing this:
http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsNT/AdminTips/Miscellaneous/DisableAltTab.html

(Registry entry should do the trick).

Also, I would look into replacing explorer as the default shell app.  Then you'll have more control over what people run.

Comment: That registry entry is absent and does not work in Windows 7 AFAIK.

Comment: does anybody know where that registry entry is in Windows10? I have seen so many sites talking about that CoolSwitch, but I do not have this line in my registry.